# Create a chatbot for stock market using IBM Watson

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red, watson-assistant

I would like to create stock bot which can have basic conversation and give me stock price in conversation.

To get stock price i am using yahoo finance api.

For basic **conversation** i am using

> IBM watson conversation api

I have also used

> IBM NLU (natural language understanding) Api

to verify different company names asked in different manner but i am not getting expected result.

For example if i search

> "What is price of INFY?"

then it should give me correct answer and should filtered out as my action should be to pass INFY in yahoo finance api. This should also work if i change format of question asked.

Below is the flow chart setup which i made on node-red panel of bluemix (IBM).

[image]

Could you help me to find out exact api's and flow which could help me achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty big one, but at least some first impression comments...

Watson Conversation Service is already integrated with NLU component - the intents and entities TAB. The company names could be extracted from the input text with the use of entities and entities synonyms. Drawback here is that the user needs to list all the possible variants of how the company name can look like, but on the other hand, the entities specification can be imported in the Conversation through a csv file.

In general the integration of Watson Conversation service and some 3rd party services needs to be done outside the Conversation service - as it as of now - does not explicitly support calling of 3rd party APIs, so the node.js solution here seems a sound one. What you need to specify is how the integration of WCS and 3rd party services will look like. The general pipeline could look like:

- user inputs text to the system
- text goes to Watson Conversation Service
- the intent and company name is extracted in WCS
- WCS sends text output + sets a special variable in the node `output` field such as `"stocks" : "Google"` that will tell the node.js component that sits after the conversation service to find out and include stocks market value of Google inside the output text

Now - back to your solution - it might make sense to have also a dedicated NLC service that will be used only to extract the companies name in the system. However I would use this only if it would turn out that e.g. `entities` in WCS service are not robust enough to capture the companies properly (my feeling here is that for this particular use case the entities with synonyms might work ok).